# Layered Classes and JSON encoding

Tags: python, json, class

I have some Data that I need to write to a JSON string.
I have it working with dict items but want to encompass it all in classes to help ensure the correct data.

The following code is a comparison between the dict items and the class item output.  They don't match, and I can't figure out what I am missing.

I get a "bound method Event.encode of Event..." in my JSON string.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import json


class Event(namedtuple('Event', 'itemName, itemID')):

    def encode(self):
        obj = {}
        obj['itemName'] = str(self.itemName)
        obj['itemID'] = int(self.itemID)

        return json.dumps(obj)

curEv = Event('MyName', 5)
print 'ClassEv : ', curEv.encode()
curEv2 = {'itemName':'MyName', 'itemID':5}
print 'DictEv  : ', json.dumps(curEv2)


class Packet(namedtuple('Packet', 'pID, itemType, itemData')):

    def encode(self):
        obj = {}
        obj['pID'] = int(self.pID)
        obj['itemType'] = int(self.itemType)
        obj['itemData'] = str(self.itemData.encode)

        return json.dumps(obj)

packet = Packet(11, 0, curEv)
print 'ClassPacket: ', packet.encode()

packet2 = {'pID':11, 'itemType':0}
packet2['itemData'] = curEv2
print 'DictPacket : ', json.dumps(packet2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are failing to call the `itemData.encode()` function. Instead you are simply returning a reference to it.

Try:

```
    obj['itemData'] = str(self.itemData.encode())
```

Note the extra `()` at the end.